# Learn to actually write in Java or just understand the code?

Tags: java, android, ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

Sorry for the newbie question but I really need to understand this .

I have tried numerous times to learn programming. Specifically java so i can move on to game development for android/ios. The truth is , i gave up every single time after a few days of self learning.

I never had troubles learning anything in my life and as a matter of fact, im a very quick learner and my common sense goes through the roof. For some reason though, programming has challenged me to the limits.

What i noticed is that, no matter how hard and complex Java becomes, i still understand the code im reading and what it does. But as for writing it down myself? I couldn't manage that even if it slapped me in the face.

With that said , i beg the question... Do i really need to know how to write every single code off by heart? or is reading and understanding the code enough for my goals? I know there are game engines i.e. Unity3d, that were developed specifically for these purposes. I even saw demo games for android built in Unity3d that look astonishing. But its hard to believe that every single game/app developer out their actually sat down and wrote the whole damn code for it.

What am i missing here? this is really not making much sense to me.

So i guess the main question im trying to ask here is .... Do i need to learn how to write every code off by heart and understand what it means? or is it enough to understand the code and its functionality, to proceed with my goals? if this is the case (with my luck it probably won't be :) ) What will be the best way to proceed from here.

Thank you and any replies will be highly appreciated.

Take me out of my misery:)

Aris

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific programming questions. If you are having an issue with a specific piece of code then please post the details and show the code. This topic would be better suited to the chat section or another forum

Comment: For conceptual questions about software development, use http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do i really need to know how to write every single code off by heart?

I wouldn't. Being able to write the code from scratch is more useful.

> or is reading and understanding the code enough for my goals?

Depends on your goals, but I doubt it.

> I know there are game engines i.e. Unity3d, that were developed specifically for these purposes.

Yes, many.

> I even saw demo games for android built in Unity3d that look astonishing. But its hard to believe that every single game/app developer out their actually sat down and wrote the whole damn code for it.

Most likely not.  Nor do you have to.

> What am i missing here?

It takes experience.  I write code much better than I did five years ago, after twenty years of coding.

> this is really not making much sense to me.

You have much more to learn.  I have two degrees but this was just the start of a twenty year career with hands on experience.

> So i guess the main question im trying to ask here is .... Do i need to learn how to write every code off by heart and understand what it means?

No. Memorizing isn't very useful. Much beter to be able to write new code yourself.  This takes LOTS of practice.

> or is it enough to understand the code and its functionality, to proceed with my goals?

What are your goals?

> What will be the best way to proceed from here.

Read this link and don't be so hard on yourself.

[Teach Yourself Programming in Ten Years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html)

Expect to be learning all the time.  The rate of development of new technologies is not slowing down and already it is more than one person can learn.  Be comfortable with the idea you only know what you need to know and you can't possibly know it all.

Comment: "So i guess the main question im trying to ask here is .... Do i need to learn how to write every code off by heart and understand what it means?

No. Memorizing isn't very useful. Much beter to be able to write new code yourself. This takes LOTS of practice."

To be clear, i meant learning how to write code from scratch as you suggested. But even then , for someone who is just learning from online tutorials, the tutorials show you how they personally write code. Which means, memorizing what they are doing. 

As for the goals: Android game development.

Comment: @user3027066 If there is a simple structure you can memorize which is useful to reuse, most likely this is a) searchable for an example of how to do this so you don't need to remember it b) a number of libraries which do it.  The bits you need to write are the uncommon and specific to your application.

Comment: @user3027066 Why memorize when you have the internet to search for stuff? What you need is hands on practice of how to solve problems.

Comment: So are you saying i should proceed with an idea i have by google searching various bits i want to put together to create something and learn while I move on ?

Comment: @user3027066 Learn to use all the tools available to you and you don't have to learn so much yourself.  I use code completion in my IDE heavily as well as the debugger, profiler, code reformatter, static analysis etc.  Learn to delegate the programming work and you will more productive.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a beginner developer also, but i give you my personal opinion. At the beginning it is much better to start with you own code and after a while when you understand what are you doing you can start to copy code of other parts but you need to know how to do a for or when used the while.

At lease myself I don't know all the codes to connect for example with a data base but i got my own code so when ever I want to connecting I go to that code and I copy it and change the things that I know that need to be change.

So what I said here, You should try to develop your code at lease once everything to know perfectly how its work and after that reused from others projects.

Answer (score 0):

You may think that you understand everything that's going on, but until you actually get experience with off-by-one errors, `null` values in unexpected places, and race conditions, you won't understand a lot of the reason for why things are done the way they are. It may not be necessary for you to learn to code yourself, if you can effectively use a library/application based on it, but you won't really understand what it's doing under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have taken a too formalistic approach to learning programming. I was bored by the typical textbooks with

```
1. History of Java
2. Variables
3. For statement
...
```

Just think of something useful for yourself, a little Android app for example, and just learn what you need on the way.

Comment: Exactly what is going on with me. Its dreadful but its the only way i can find on the internet of learning how to program, variables, if , else .. history and such

Answer (score 0):

Try to write simple programs first. The more you write code, the better you understand it. No one can learn programming just by reading books or written codes. Programming looks hard at first but eventually it becomes a second nature.
Never memorize code. Nothing good ever comes out of it. Just understand what a particular class do and IDe will help you in writing methods and properties. Almost any IDE these days has an Auto-complete feature.
Don't fret by the amount of code you see in an application. Lots of them are generated automatically by game engine, though you should understand what they mean and do.
To give an example this is the source code of a simple converter application I made. You can see how much code is here but with Netbeans IDE I have just written two lines of that, all other are auto generated.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Home;

/**
 *
 * @author Windows8
 */
public class CelsiusConverterGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form CelsiusConverterGUI
     */
    public CelsiusConverterGUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        tempTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        celsiusLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        convertButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        fahrenheitLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Celsius Converter");

        celsiusLabel.setText("Celsius");

        convertButton.setText("Convert");
        convertButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                convertButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        fahrenheitLabel.setText("Fahrenheit");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(tempTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(celsiusLabel))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(convertButton)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(fahrenheitLabel)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {convertButton, tempTextField});

        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(tempTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(celsiusLabel))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(convertButton)
                    .addComponent(fahrenheitLabel))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void convertButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        //Parse the celsius input into double
        int tmpFah = (int) ((Double.parseDouble(tempTextField.getText())) * 1.8 + 32);
        fahrenheitLabel.setText(tmpFah + " Fahrenheit");
    }                                             

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CelsiusConverterGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CelsiusConverterGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CelsiusConverterGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CelsiusConverterGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new CelsiusConverterGUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel celsiusLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton convertButton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel fahrenheitLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tempTextField;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Hey and thanks! You wrote 2 lines but you found the rest in the library and added it to the code, right ?

Comment: @user3027066 Even easier than that. For example to generate a code for showing a button on page you just drag the button and drop it in design surface. Netbeans will take care of generating the code. Or you just pick a button event from a menu and the code for that event will be generated. Things are exactly the same in C# development of WPF and asp.net applications.